# finding an ip used illegally on a network switch

Tags: networking, ip

- In our college there are many IP addresses for every labs for example
  our it lab has IP range of 172.16.24.* and cs lab as 172.16.22.*.
- How to find which cs lab IP is being used illegally in our lab?
- We have a switch for each lab. Is there a way to find IP used
  illegally through our switch with outgoing packets?

> i tried nmap -sP

but that shows the ranges of the IP addresses i want which of them are from our switch... Please help.

Comment: Switches don't have any knowledge of IP addresses.

Comment: Any other means of finding an IP used in that way. i.e Other range of ip in a network. Please help.

Comment: I tried nslookup, arp too they give ip of the system on network. But not what I expected is there any corrections for those cmds to get my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "which IP is being used illegally"? Do you mean someone might use an IP that is supposed for a workstation in a lab? If that is the case, then you can list all 'legal' MAC addresses of the computers in the labs and then compare with the MAC addresses listed in the ARP table of the switch.

If you want to be more strict, then you can implement static MAC address on each port and shut down all other unused ports on that switch.

Comment: For your reference: If some one in our lab (has no internet) is using an IP of another lab (with internet). Is there a way to find which ip of that other lab is used in our lab. That s my question. Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works after you changed the IP? I assume that you're using different VLANs for these two labs. If someone changed an IP and used the IP from other lab, then I don't think that PC's connection will work. This is because the gateway for the VLAN assigned to that lab is in different IP range.